# Graylog: Saving search when there are no results

Tags: graylog2

I just recently setup GrayLog2 and adding searches and streams as we go along.
Since it's a relatively new setup, Graylog doesn't have all the logs yet.

But we want to save searches for certain kinds of logs. When we search in GrayLog for those now, we obviously don't get any results.

In such a case, how do we save the searches i.e. when there are no results.
When there are results, it shows a "Save Search" button.

Comment: Just encountered this, pretty annoying, looks like we will have to manually add the query we are looking out for to an old log file